# Specify path for qrc_foo.cpp file in qmake project file

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

Trying to keep my project folder clean by movimg all temporarily files to `/tmp` which works fine for moc files and objects with `OBJECTS_DIR = tmp/` and `MOC_DIR = tmp/`. Now the only temporary file at top level is the `qrc_something.cpp`.

Isn't there a variable for that output in the `.pro` file? I could not find it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

Makefile looks like this:

```
tmp/qrc_configwizard.o: qrc_configwizard.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o tmp/qrc_configwizard.o qrc_configwizard.cpp
```

I could add the `tmp/` there but that would be very inconvenient (or should it rather be in src? At least not top level, or?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you're looking for is called `RCC_DIR`.

May I suggest to use a **shadow build** instead of playing with these variables?

- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `qmake ../../path/to/source.pro`
- `make`

Done, source directory clean of build artifacts.

Comment: This also avoids using a shared `/tmp` which can be a security/etc. problem

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will get familiar with it.